# VLC suddenly keeps popping up with JAVA logo and ASCii colour art

Tags: java, vlc, ubuntu-mate, hacking, ascii-art

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS. I've installed it just yesterday and updated it immediately. Today I start my system up and VLC keeps popping up out of nowhere. It shows in a small window the JAVA logo (coffee cup). I closed that and after I closed it, it popped up again with ASCii colour art showing (that was the title at top). I keep closing it but it keeps popping up.

Actions:
- Deleted VLC player: Still pops up VLC somehow.
- Deleted JAVA completely: Stopped popping up.

Question: 
- How come VLC keeps popping up even when i deleted it? (purge command) 
- Was I being hacked? 
- Do I have to do a fresh install?

Answer (score 1):

Since everything in Linux is a file, a running process is as such as well a file which is located in the `/proc` folder in which you **should not mess around in by hand** the probability is very high that at least one task of VLC kept that file for the process alive. So normally a simple reboot after uninstalling VLC would probably have solved it.

About your question if you have been hacked. I can't tell. But for sure sounds iffy somehow, and if I where you I would do a fresh install just to be sure.